# Best way to convert parts of a string to int to convert from binary to float JAVA

Tags: java, math, binary, formula, exponent

I am writing a program where I have strings of 9 bits of "0" and "1" to convert to exponent (taking each index and doing 2 ^ n from right to left).

**example: ["1","0","1"] = 2^2 + 0^1 + 2^0**

I know this is wrong because of the errors I am getting but am confused what to do which will calculate it in an efficient manner.

```
expoBefore = (strNum.charAt(9)) * 1 + (strNum.charAt(8)) * 2 + (strNum.charAt(7)) * 4 + (strNum.charAt(6)) * 8 + (strNum.charAt(5)) * 16 + (strNum.charAt(4)) * 32 + (strNum.charAt(3)) *  64 + (strNum.charAt(8)) * 128;
```

for example for one of the strings I am passing through [11111111] I want it to add 1 * 2^0 + 1 * 2 ^1 + 1 * 2^2.....etc

**Clarification edit:**

**What is a more efficient way of converting a string of 0's and 1's to an integer?**

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to convert a binary string to its integer value?

Comment: Hint: This could be done with a loop

Comment: @Tyler, if you understand this problem, could you do us all a favor and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58701365/edit) their question to help others as well?

Comment: @FailingCoder done, needs peer review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop.

Iterate over the binary string. For each character, add 2^*x* to an accumulator if the bit is set (where *x* is the position of the bit), otherwise, add 0.

```java
String binary = "11111111";
int number = 0;

for(int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char c = binary.charAt(i);

    number += Integer.parseInt(c + "") * Math.pow(2, binary.length() - i - 1);
}

System.out.println(number); // prints 255
```

[How to convert binary to decimal](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/how-binary-to-decimal.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to multiply a character's ascii value with an integer.
You must take the integer value of this character and then multiply it with another integer. Hope this helps.

```
String str = "111";
int x = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(0));
int y = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(1));
int z = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(2));

System.out.println(x + y + z);
```

Output:
3

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop and increment down to miniplate each number

Answer (score 0):

It is very inefficient to use `Math.pow(2, i)` in a loop.
Faster to keep the previous value and multiply by 2 each time through (code untested):

```
int ip = 1;
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = binary.length -1; i >= 0) {
   if ( binary.charAt(i) == '1' ) {
      sum += ip;
   }
   ip *= 2;
}
```

You may want to use long ints if the number gets large.
Also, be sure to check that `binary` contains only zeroes and ones.